# I am getting "Key Error" Exception in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, image, data-science

*Getting **Key Error 0** in the following code where some_digit = X[0]*

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import the dataset
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version = 1)
mnist.keys()

#shape of the data
X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
X.shape

#there are 70000 images and each has 784 features because each image has 28*28 pixel from which we are displaying one image

some_digit = X[0]
some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28,28)
plt.imshow(some_digit_image, cmap="binary")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

**The dataset contains 7000 images of 28 * 28 pixels each. I am trying to fetch an image at location X[0].**
please help

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, it's otherwise impossible to answer without random guesses

Comment: Please read with the fetch_openml function actually returns: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_openml.html

Answer (score 1):

`X` is a dataframe where columns are pixel values and rows are different images:
[image]

When you do `X[0]` you are asking for the column 0, but columns are named `pixel<number>`. What you want is the data of image 0, so

```
X.iloc[0]
```

To make the rest of your code work, we can convert that result to a numpy array:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import the dataset
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version = 1)
mnist.keys()

#shape of the data
X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
X.shape

#there are 70000 images and each has 784 features because each image has 28*28 pixel from which we are displaying one image

import numpy as np
some_digit = np.array(X.iloc[0])
some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28,28)
plt.imshow(some_digit_image, cmap="binary")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```